# How can I display images on the output screen using ASCII code in C++?

Tags: c++, image, ascii, bgi

**Note---- I use BORLAND TURBO C++**

I know that Turbo C++ is two decades old, and it does not support the latest C++ standard either. But since our school still uses it to teach students C++, I can't use any other compiler.

I want to display an image in Turbo C++ using ASCII text. I have already converted the image to ASCII code using an online converter. What should I do now to display it in my program?

I was thinking of something along these lines-

1. Copy the ASCII code to a txt file.
2. Read the text file using the getline function.
3. Display it on the output screen.

I thought it would work, but the difficulty arises when I copy the ASCII image to notepad. It destroys all the formatting of the ASCII image, and the image just becomes a rectangular block of text.

Is there any other way to achieve this? I do not want to use any other libraries if I can help it. I use the graphics.h library in Turbo C++. Also, I am a bit new to C++ (started learning it last year), so I would be grateful if you keep the answers as simple as possible.

Comment: Why does it need "copying to Notepad" -- a step you seem to consider necessary? And how can ASCII text 'loose formatting'?

Comment: I need to read the ASCII text from a text file to display it on the screen. So I need to paste the ASCII code in a text file editor so that I can save it. And by losing the formatting I mean that when I copy the text to notepad, all the spaces are deleted.

Comment: 1. You can save the output from the on-line converter right out of your web browser. 2. Notepad, crappy as it is, usually does not delete spaces; inspect the output of the converter to find out why.

Comment: When I copy the text to Word, it retains the formatting of the text. The reason why I think Notepad does not is probably because of the large number of characters in the text, more than 5000, and maybe because of the complex formatting of the text? I used the picascii.com online converter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first option is to find another online converter which gives you a raw, copy-able, output. In that case you can use your approach.

The second way is to build an ascii converter yourself. The way I think the online tools convert an image into ascii characters is the following:

Build a table with relative brightness, so:
space is 0 brightness,
8 = 60% brightness 
0 is 80% birghtness
# is 90% brightness
and go on like this.

1. Divide the image into blocks (for example 10*10 pixels)
2. Determine the average brightness of such a block
3. Find an ascii-character with approximately the same relative brightness.
4. print image.

this is more complicated, and if you are new you could probably try your approach first.

Comment: The converter I use does give me a copy-able output. When I copy the ascii code to MS Word, it retains its formatting perfectly. But when I copy it to notepad, it loses all its formatting. So the problem here does not lie with the converter.

Comment: For me it works just fine, if I choose the "Get text version", and copy in notepad it kinda shows the image. Maybe your input image is way too large to print on the screen? In that case notepad maybe shows one line on multiple lines on your screen and this results in a strange output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was copying the text into notepad the wrong way. The get-text option worked fine.  I was able to copy the ascii image into notepad and display it in my program.